# Clicker Counter Lag

Tags: c#, performance, lag

So I've just started coding and i'm probably using a very rudimentary method to do this but i wanted to make a click counter so i can make a 'Drop Log' for Runescape. Everything's going smooth however I've noticed that after X amount of Clicker counters programmed the buttons start to lag? Debug isn't popping up with any issues, its kind of just getting stuck?

Here's my code:

```
namespace DropLog_v2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Pernix Counts
    int CountP = 0;
    int CountP2 = 0;
    int CountP3 = 0;
    int CountP4 = 0;
    int CountP5 = 0;
    int CountP6 = 0;
    //Virtus Counts
    int CountV = 0;
    int CountV2 = 0;
    int CountV3 = 0;
    int CountV4 = 0;
    int CountV5 = 0;
    int CountV6 = 0;
    int CountV7 = 0;
    //Torva Counts
    int CountM = 0;
    public Form1()   
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Move Window
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Left += e.X - lastPoint.X;
            this.Top += e.Y - lastPoint.Y;
        }
    }
    Point lastPoint;
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lastPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }
    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Left += e.X - lastPoint.X;
            this.Top += e.Y - lastPoint.Y;
        }
    }
    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lastPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }
    //Close Window
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    //Pernix Buttons
    private void Pernix1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountP++;
            PernixL1.Text = CountP.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountP > 0)
                CountP--;
            PernixL1.Text = CountP.ToString();
        }

    }
    private void Pernix2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountP2++;
            PernixL2.Text = CountP2.ToString();
        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountP2 > 0)
                CountP2--;
            PernixL2.Text = CountP2.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Pernix3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountP3++;
            PernixL3.Text = CountP3.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountP3 > 0)
                CountP3--;
            PernixL3.Text = CountP3.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Pernix4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountP4++;
            PernixL4.Text = CountP4.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountP4 > 0)
                CountP4--;
            PernixL4.Text = CountP4.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Pernix5_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountP5++;
            PernixL5.Text = CountP5.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountP5 > 0)
                CountP5--;
            PernixL5.Text = CountP5.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Pernix6_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountP6++;
            PernixL6.Text = CountP6.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountP6 > 0)
                CountP6--;
            PernixL6.Text = CountP6.ToString();
        }
    }
    //Virtus Buttons
    private void Virtus1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountV++;
            VirtusL1.Text = CountV.ToString();
        }
     else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountV > 0)
                CountV--;
            VirtusL1.Text = CountV.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Virtus2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountV2++;
            VirtusL2.Text = CountV2.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountV2 > 0)
                CountV2--;
            VirtusL2.Text = CountV2.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Virtus3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountV3++;
            VirtusL3.Text = CountV3.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountV3 > 0)
                CountV3--;
            VirtusL3.Text = CountV3.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Virtus4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountV4++;
            VirtusL4.Text = CountV4.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountV4 > 0)
                CountV4--;
            VirtusL4.Text = CountV4.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Virtus5_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountV5++;
            VirtusL5.Text = CountV5.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountV5 > 0)
                CountV5--;
            VirtusL5.Text = CountV5.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Virtus6_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountV6++;
            VirtusL6.Text = CountV6.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountV6 > 0)
                CountV6--;
            VirtusL6.Text = CountV6.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void Virtus7_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountV7++;
            VirtusL7.Text = CountV7.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountV7 > 0)
                CountV7--;
            VirtusL7.Text = CountV7.ToString();
        }
    }
    //Torva Buttons
    private void Torva1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CountM++;
            TorvaL1.Text = CountM.ToString();
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (CountM > 0)
                CountM--;
            TorvaL1.Text = CountM.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

}

All was working Great until i tried doing the next line of code for the first 'torva' clicker and now its become laggy..

All help is appreciated (Novice, so please go easy)

Comment: You have MouseMove instead of MouseDown. Is that on purpose? Doing these calculations every time your mouse moves is indeed going to be laggy.

Comment: oooh thankyou! i just noticed i must have clicked the wrong event haha been at this for over 12 hours now. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have MouseMove instead of MouseDown